# init.d script for OpenXCAP on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, init.d, centos6

I'm somewhat new to Linux and OpenXCAP and I'm trying to make an init.d script for OpenXCAP on CentOS 6.

My script can **start** and **stop** OpenXCAP service, but it returns this error for the **status** command (service openxcap status): **openxcap dead but subsys locked**

Maybe somebody can tell me if problem is in the init.d script or the openxcap service itself? Is openxcap missing some 'give-status' feature?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Startup script for OpenXCAP
#
# processname: openxcap
# pidfile: /var/run/openxcap/openxcap.pid
# chkconfig: - 85 15
# description: start, stop, restart OpenXCAP server
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: openxcap
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network
# Should-Start: mysqld
### END INIT INFO

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

APP_NAME=openxcap
APP_HOME=/usr/local/src/openxcap-2.0.1
PID_PATH=/var/run/openxcap/openxcap.pid
RETVAL=0

[ -f /etc/sysconfig/$APP_NAME ] && . /etc/sysconfig/$APP_NAME

start()
{
        echo -n $"Starting $APP_NAME: "
        daemon $APP_HOME/$APP_NAME $OPTIONS 2>/dev/null | tail -1
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$APP_NAME
}

stop()
{
        echo -n $"Stopping $APP_NAME: "
        killproc -p $PID_PATH
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$APP_NAME $PID_PATH
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
        start)
                start
                ;;
        stop)
                stop
                ;;
        status)
                status $APP_NAME
                RETVAL=$?
                ;;
        restart|reload)
                stop
                start
                ;;
        *)
                echo $"Usage: $APP_NAME {start|stop|reload|restart|status|help}"
                exit 1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Answer (score 0):

You are (hopefully) writing out a PID file as `/var/run/openxcap/openxcap.pid`.

I suspect that your program is writing out one PID, but then starting another process. The first process dies, so `sysvinit` doesn't know to look for a different one.

However, the lock file indicating that your process was started is still present.

You may not be able to directly use the `daemon` function for starting this program; you might need to create a customized version that is “smart enough” to identify the correct PID.

Comment: Hi @BRPocock, first sorry for late reply. Now regarding the issue itself, this OpenXCAP service is a python application and maybe there is solution for this problem for python apps in general. I just haven't found it yet.  
And not to mention that this OpenXCAP project didn't see any updates for a while and I am considering dropping it from my project.